# How to set height of imageview when no constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

In  this image, `height` of images in `imageview` are long. if i try to give constraint height, then the imageview with no image also gets height which i dont want since i want to collapse the tableviewcell with no image.

Its working fine with no image now but only problem is the height.

[image]

Comment: Read about auto layout with `UITableViewCell`'s.

Comment: I tried Auto Layout too.

Comment: You want imageview to be size of the image? Then try yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:
::Put a constraint of height on ImageView
::Take an outlet of constraint
::If there is no image then make constraint.constant to 0 otherwise dont change the constraint.

Comment: It worked but then when i am scrolling, the images are getting messed up and the tableviewcell with images are showing no image.  FYI: I am getting values from corredata.

Comment: Sound like there might be something wrong with how you reuse cells. Please show your all your table view methods that create cells and/or fill them with data.

Comment: Table view reuses the cells so while creating the cells just check whether there is an image : if no image then constraint.constant=0 else set the constraint.constant to the height that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Images are represented as instances of UIImage class, but this class does not show the image. It works the class UIImageView which has the property image which is UIImage. UIIMageView will present(show) the image contained in it's .image property using dimensions defined in image.size property. So, if you want to change the height, you can do this using the following code:

myImageView.frame.size.height = 50 // or calculate and put here your height

Every instance of UITableViewCell already has an imageView property which is UIImageView and you can access it and control it programmatically.